# How to explain to esl students that grade comes before class, in the opinion of school levels. For example: I'm in grade 2, class 7

Tags: grammar

I can't find a definitive answer about why grade comes before the class number of schools.

Comment: What sort of reason are you expecting? I suspect it's because the grade tells you more about their age & level of education than the class number does.

Comment: I'm in class 7 of grade 2. Just as good, unless you crave a top-down order.

Comment: In the English-speaking world we do general to specific or big to small in many things: feet and inches, dollars and cents, times (12.45), binomial species names, US month-date, names in the phone book. But we often do specific to general or small to big: UK day-month dates, addresses (street-city-country), city-state pairs ("Detroit, MI"), first name-last name, month-year. There's no universal standard about many, e.g. whether apartment numbers/letters come before or after building numbers. There's no general principle.

Comment: Are you talking about language, or the convention of some academic structure? I'm not actually familiar with a structure that divides grades into classes. Please explain more about the context of your question.

Comment: This is just the convention of your school (and many other schools).  It is not a rule of English.  There is a kind of logic to a "top down" structure, but not always. I don't think an answer to your question can be written, so I think the questions should be closed.

Comment: I've encountered both "second grade" and "grade two", it's very much a product of the system.